# How to allow a Server with a Private static IP to connect to the internet

Tags: web, server, static-ip-address

I have developed an Enterprise Web App for my company that need to run on a private network. I have assigned the in house server a static IP so to make path to system constant for the users. The problem is that the web application makes calls to Twilio SMS gateway to send SMS to clients via the system but with my our current setup, its impossible since the Server is denied internet access. So how to I expose this server to the internet??

Answer (score 1):

What I have seen quite often in corporate environments is the use of a HTTP proxy to let internal systems call other systems on the internet. Maybe there is a HTTP proxy available in your corporate environment that you can use. This would be the easiest way of doing this without having to change the infrastructure.